# Enabling Reporting Services 2005 on VS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, visual-studio-2012

I have this SSRS Reports SQL 2005 and i need this to attached on my MVC Application using VS 2012.

VS 2012 Report Viewer version 11 doesn't support RS 2005 and supports only RS 2008 later that's why i added report viewer version 9.0 to my toolbox.

I created Webform Page where report viewer will be attached but when it doesn't render to the from and says.

```
Error Creating Control - ReportViewer1 Failed to created designer ......
```

Does anyone can provide the details to deal with this Issue.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all other other people who encountered
`Error Creating Control` and  `'RSClientController' is undefined` when attaching ReportViewer version 9.0 to VS 2012, i got the solution.

What i did is to set my web config file and asp.net source below

Report.aspx

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
```

Web.Config

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*"  path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</httpHandlers>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
       <add name="Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Even though on the Designer View, Report Viewer still show Error Creating Control but when you run your application, the report will render normally.

Hope this will help you.

Best Regards